# php post form with variable and javascript submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a list of items from a database and I am trying to post to a specific entry in that list using javascript to submit a form. I have no idea why it's not working though. Here is my code...

```
<?php
...
while loop to get results {
echo "<form action='scheduled.php?id=$row[id]' method='post' id='sche'>";
echo "<td onclick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('sche').submit();\">".$row['firstname'];
echo "</td>";
echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

The weird part is that it WILL post, but it doesn't pull the right 'id'. It will take the first one on the list and post to that 'id'.

my URL reads "...scheduled.php?id="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the loop, you are defining many different forms with the same id "sche". You need to give each element their own id.

```
<?php
...
while loop to get results {
echo "<form action='scheduled.php?id=$row[id]' method='post' id='sche_$row[id]'>";
echo "<td onclick=\"javascript:document.getElementById('sche_$row[id]').submit();\">".$row['firstname'];
echo "</td>";
echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Notice the new `sche_$row[id]` for "id"

Comment: YES! This is exactly right. Yes, that makes total sense now. Thank you!

Comment: Think it is a good praxis to separate variables in string with curly brackets (also good for object methods): `echo "This is id: {$row['id']}"`.